# Solve this integral $\int_0^9x^9\sqrt{x^3 + 2}dx$

Tags: integration

$I = \displaystyle\int\limits_0^9x^9\sqrt{x^3 + 2}dx$

I let $u = \sqrt{x^3 +2}$

Then $I = \dfrac23\displaystyle\int\limits_{\sqrt2}^{\sqrt{731}}u^2(u^2 -2)^2\sqrt[3]{u^2 -2}du$

After that, I let $t = u^2 -2$

And I got:

$I =\dfrac13\displaystyle\int\limits_0^{729}t^2\sqrt{t +2}\sqrt[3]{t}dt$

And I can't go furthur.

And idea or better way to solve it, please help!??

Comment: Do you need an approximate value for your integral?

Comment: Try $u = x^3 + 2$.

Comment: [You'll need](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E9*sqrt%28x%5E3%2B2%29+from+0+to+9) the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Is it possible that the question has a typo? It's much easier if you have $x^8$ rather than $x^9$.

Comment: @preferred_anon. You are mre than probably correct (otherwise, it is anightmare).

Comment: It doesn't have a typo and yes, it's truly a nightmare :(

Answer (score 1):

*This is a very tricky approach to the solution.*

Consider that
$$\sqrt{x^3+\epsilon}=x^{3/2}+\frac{\epsilon }{2 x^{3/2}}-\frac{\epsilon ^2}{8 x^{9/2}}+\frac{\epsilon
   ^3}{16 x^{15/2}}+O\left(\epsilon ^4\right)$$ I do not introduce the next term because muliplied by $x^9$, it will contain a negative power of $x$ (what we cannot afford.

Make $\epsilon=2$ and muliply by $x^9$. So we compute
$$\int_0^9 \Big[x^{21/2}+x^{15/2}-\frac{x^{9/2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3/2}}{2}  \Big]\,dx=\frac{176374123741638}{21505}$$ which is $\sim 8.20154028094\times 10^9$ while the exact solution (obtained using the hypergeometric function is
$$\frac{176132680620646 }{34155}\sqrt{\frac{43}{17}}-\frac{7168 \sqrt{2} }{580635}\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{3};-\frac{729}{2}\right)$$ that is to say $8.20154028011\times 10^9$